# Connect to AS400 database with Django (ibm_db_django)

Tags: django, pycharm, ibm-midrange

I have created a new project in Django and am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLPuey73as0) to help me pull data from my remote database. Whenever I try to run **migrate** in *manage.py* I get the following error:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.1\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\ecjohnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.1\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" migrate U:/incoming_parts_monitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ecjohnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 585, in connect
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '', conn_options)
 SQLCODE=-30081

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ecjohnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ecjohnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

I've connected to this database before in other .NET web applications so I'm not sure why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlcode=-30081 is a generic "unable to connect" condition. Look to the configuration and connection details, on both the requesting and server systems, and review for any messaging about a connection issue on the server side [of possible assist is a review of the Display Log (DSPLOG) for the history (QHST), and then review of the joblog(s) of the job(s) that originated that messaging] as an indication that the communications-level connection was at least completed, but some error after that initial comm connection prevented establishing an actual database connection; e.g. perhaps the prestart job or the subsystem in which the database server jobs operate is not started.